# How does Gitlab register a runner on a Docker container?

Tags: docker, gitlab, centos7

I'm attempting to register a Gitlab runner using Docker (running on Centos 7.6) using the following documentation:

https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/docker.html#docker-images
https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/index.html#docker

This documentation basically instructs me to (1) run the runner and then (2) register it:

1. I run the runner:

`docker run -d --name my-gitlab-runner --restart always \
      -v /srv/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner \
      -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
      gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest`

2. I register the runner (which completes without issue):

`docker run --rm -t -i -v /srv/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner gitlab/gitlab-runner register`

The registration documentation referred to by the 2nd URL mentions "In this section, you will launch an ephemeral gitlab-runner container to register the **container** that you created during install."

My problem is that I don't see where/how this registration process links the container that I created in step 1 with the Gitlab runner.  The registration links the runner with an image but not an actual container instance.  The registration isn't run from within the container created in step 1.  How does Gitlab know that the runner I have just registered corresponds to the container that I created in step 1 and not some other container.

I must be missing something obvious so any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What you try to achieve? You want GitLab runner able to start job inside docker image?

Comment: Inside a container, yes.  As per Gitlab documentation, it's possible to have a runner run as a docker container as opposed to a physical or virtual machine.  I'm just struggling to figure out how the registration maps the runner to the container itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both containers (the temporary one and the actual gitlab-runner instance) share a volume together `-v /srv/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner` in which the registration token is stored. The actual instance of the runner can then use that token from the generated config to authenticate with the gitlab instance.

Comment: Thanks Pat - I was thinking along those lines originally.  But if that volume (and the config.toml) is shared among multiple runners, I lose that 1:1 mapping.  Is the implication that the volume specified in the commands must be unique to one Gitlab runner?  In other words, if I have four Gitlab runner containers, I'll need four separate volumes and not one shared among all four containers?  The .toml file appears to allow multiple runner references in one file.

Comment: One runner instance can actually be multiple runner configurations in gitlab. However if you want dedicated processes per runner you would indeed need to change up that volume for each instance. Perhaps using a named volume instead of a host shared one like you are currently using.

Comment: Yes - I think I'll use volumes as opposed to bind mounts.  I think what threw me is that the original owner used the same bind mount for running and registering multiple gitlab runners.  So, effectively, multiple gitlab runners were using the same authentication.

Answer (score 1):

I use this command

```
sudo docker run --rm -it -v /srv/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner gitlab/gitlab-runner register
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of starting container at host machine (that one who has docker installed), you register your runner usual way:

```
sudo gitlab-runner register
```

But as executor you specify - docker

Comment: That's what step 2 does.  It runs the register command within a temporary container.  I have no issue with the registration process.  It completes fine.  As I say, I'm trying to figure out how the registration process maps the container to the Gitlab runner.

Comment: Do not register within _inside_  temporary docker. Register at host machine. GitLab will create docker containers itself.